# How can i make jquery masonry have fluid height?

Tags: jquery, widget, jquery-masonry

I'm searching for a flexible (height+width) widgets layout with drag and drop option. I want the widgets to have minimum and maximum height and width and that all be re-sized when re-sizing the browser window.

It must support both chrome and safari.

I already found the "css3 flexbox" but it has some problems when i want one of the widgets to have both scroll and flexible height.

I found the "jquery masonry" and want to change it to have flexible height(now it has content oriented height). 
I wondered if someone already did that or alternatively found a control which does that?